# Convert 1D 16bit image data to 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1D array of size 18874568 created from bytes as shown below

```
np_img = np.array(list(data), dtype=np.uint16)
```

How can I convert this to a 2D array of size 3072 x 3072 and in 8bit?

The bytes data is acquired from a image capture device called as a flat panel detector (FPD). It's specified in the docs that the FPD captures 16bit image of size 3072x3072.

16bit raw image is attached below
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kw1UeKOaBGtXNpxGsCXEk-gjGw3YaDJJ/view?usp=sharing

Edit: C# code on conversion given by the FPD support team

```
    private Bitmap Load16bppGrayImage(string fileName, int offset=0)
    {
        Bitmap loadind_bmp;
        var raw = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName).Skip(offset).ToArray();
        var pwi = 3072;
        var phi = 3072;
        var dpiX = 96d;
        var dpiY = 96d;

        loadind_bmp = new Bitmap(pwi, phi, PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb);

        BitmapData bmpData = loadind_bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, loadind_bmp.Width, loadind_bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, loadind_bmp.PixelFormat);
        int depth = Bitmap.GetPixelFormatSize(bmpData.PixelFormat) / 16;
        IntPtr srcAdr = bmpData.Scan0;

        unsafe
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bmpData.Height; y++)
            {
                int pos = y * bmpData.Stride / 3;
                ushort* imgPtr = (y * bmpData.Stride / 2) + (ushort*)bmpData.Scan0;

                for (int x = 0; x < bmpData.Width; x++)
                {
                    ushort value = (ushort)(raw[pos + (x * sizeof(ushort)) + 1] << 8 | raw[pos + x * sizeof(ushort)]);

                    imgPtr[x * depth] = value;    //Blue 0-255
                    imgPtr[x * depth + 1] = value;   //Green   0-255
                    imgPtr[x * depth + 2] = value;  //Red 0-255
                }
            }
        }

        loadind_bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        return loadind_bmp;

    }
```

Comment: If `data` is of type `bytes`, why are you making a list from it rather than using `np.frombuffer()`?

Comment: The crucial thing here would be to know the encoding of the 16-bit data. If it's RGB data, chances are it could be e.g. in 565 format, where 5 bits of each 16-bit value are for the red channel, 6 are for the green channel (since human eyes are more accurate around greens, IIRC), and the remaining 5 for the blue channel. (If you can share those docs, that would be grand.)

Comment: @MarkSetchell When I use `np.frombuffer` the resulting array is of shape 9437284. I know that the buffer size is 18874568 because there's an sdk function that returns size. why is it different?

Comment: @AKX That's not specified in the docs. They barely have any info. Also I'm not allowed to share the docs so sorry about that. We can assume 565 format because that conversion works through IrfanView software

Comment: But 3072x3072x2 is not equal to 18874568.

Comment: The data you've posted is 18874568 bytes long; `sqrt(18874568/2)` is > 3072, so there has to be some other data than just raw image data in there (18874568-(3072*3072*2) = 200 bytes to be exact).

Comment: This is my concern also. @MechanicPig. I'm not sure what that extra 200 bytes are. But the conversion works fine through IrfanView Software. I've attached a gdrive link with the raw image if you want to experiment.

Comment: Can you show the result you get with IrfanView (even downscaled or redacted or whatever)? If I just skip the first 200 bytes and convert the image as raw RGB565 (using ffmpeg), I get a very green image.

Comment: Msybe you can show a screengrab of what parameters you input into IrfanView?

Comment: Also: are you expecting an RGB image or a grayscale image?

Comment: grayscale. I'll edit the question to show a screengrab

Comment: Well, for grayscale, I get a dark image (that has some detail in it if you brighten it enough) with `dd if=data1.raw bs=200 skip=1 | ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt gray16le -video_size 3072x3072 -i - -y -f image2 data2.png` – i.e. interpreting the file past the first 200 bytes as a bunch of little-endian 16-byte values.

Comment: @Arki99 Any news on the screengrab? :)

Comment: @AKX so that FPD SDK support guys replied back to me with a C# code on the conversion (after ages). I'll update the question. Also you wont find any details on the image. it should be just white. I'm still not sure about the 200 bytes.

Comment: Right, so based on 48bppRgb, it's actually 16 bits _per channel_...

Comment: @AKX So, now we are short of data... we need 3072*3072*3*2 bytes.

Comment: The Fpd image is combined by the header(96 bytes) + image data (Width * Height * 2) + extra infomation(100 bytes) + CRC(4 bytes) - Their reply

Comment: @MarkSetchell. Same value is being stored in RGB channels. I don't need that. We can consider 3072*3072*2

Comment: That gives a very flat grey image. Correct? Please click [edit] and add your own interpretation of the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Right, based on all of the information gathered by the comments, I think you'll want something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image as Image

with open("data1.raw", "rb") as fp:
    data = fp.read()

w = h = 3072
dt = np.dtype(np.uint16).newbyteorder("<")  # little-endian
image = np.frombuffer(data, offset=96, count=w * h, dtype=dt).reshape((h, w))

# Dump to 16bpp TIFF:
Image.fromarray(image).save("data1.tiff")
```

The resulting image is quite dark, not "just white" – maybe it needs to be inverted? Who knows... :)

Comment: Actually, I was just thinking `np.fromfile()` with `offset` and `count` might be a fraction cleaner than `open()` and `read()`... Don't get me wrong, it's good already ;-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sure, but OP says they have a `data` already. :)

Comment: D'oh! I better go put the kettle on - I clearly need more coffee!

Answer (score 0):

Use `ndarray.view`:

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(2 ** 7, 2 ** 12, 10, dtype=np.uint16)
>>> a
array([3434, 1565, 3144,  357, 3755, 3130, 3799,  338, 3224, 2794],
      dtype=uint16)
>>> a.view(np.uint8)
array([106,  13,  29,   6,  72,  12, 101,   1, 171,  14,  58,  12, 215,
        14,  82,   1, 152,  12, 234,  10], dtype=uint8)
```

The better way is to read with uint8 instead of uint16 before conversion. You should refer to: [Input and output](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/routines.io.html)

Comment: Couldn't you just reinterpret an uint16 matrix as an uint8 array without any manual shifting?